# writing a python program to manipulate a fasta file

Tags: python, string, fasta

Suppose i have the following fasta file and text file:

```
#fasta
>seq1
AAATTTCCC
>seq2
CCCGGGTTT

#txt (tab seperated)
seq1 3
seq2 4
```

I need help trying to write a program that will repeat the string for each seq in the fasta n times.Thanks in advance!

```
#output fasta
>seq1
AAATTTCCCAAATTTCCCAAATTTCCC
>seq2
CCCGGGTTTCCCGGGTTTCCCGGGTTTCCCGGGTTT
```

Comment: how to differentiate two parts in the file? and does the file include comments also?

Comment: they're two seperate files but have the sequence name (se1, seq2) in common. No comments in either file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('fasta.txt') as fp, open('seq.txt') as fp2:
    data = [line.strip() for line in fp if line.strip()]
    seq = [line.split() for line in fp2 if line.strip()]
data = dict([(data[i], data[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(data), 2)])

with open('output.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for x in seq:
        key = '>' + x[0]
        fw.write(key + '\n' + data[key] * int(x[1]) + '\n')

#output.txt
#>seq1
#AAATTTCCCAAATTTCCCAAATTTCCC
#>seq2
#CCCGGGTTTCCCGGGTTTCCCGGGTTTCCCGGGTTT
```